Integration with respect to functions
I observe some strange behaviour of Mathematica when pulling functions into the integrator. I know that Mathematica's capabilities are limited when computing Stieltje or Lebesgue Integrals. But even simple outputs behave quite strangely:
Integrate[f'[x], x]
Integrate[1, f[x]]

Gives, correctly:
f[x]
f[x]

But
Integrate[x  f'[x], x]
Integrate[x, f[x]]

Returns quite strangely:

Hence, as @Ulrich Neumann suggests, the second formulation contains the implicit assumption that g'[x] is Riemann integrable. It seems that Mathematica treats f[x] as a separate variable with not dependence on x.

Probably Mathematica "knows"  Integrate[x, f[x]]==Integrate[x f'[x]],x]

You can write is as
\begin{align*}
\int xd\left(  f\left(  x\right)  \right)    & =\int x\frac{df}{dx}dx\\
& =\int xf^{\prime}dx
\end{align*}
And  Mathematica gives now
 Integrate[x*f'[x], x]



I do not understand how Mathematica operates when Integrating with
respect to functions

It looks like you need to reformulate the command yourself like the above so that the integration is with respect to a variable and not a function.
I do not know why Mathematica gave the result it did with your input.
update
fyi, I tried this in Rubi, and Maple 20204 and Fricas and Maxima and XCas/GIAC. Out of these, maxima and giac returned back same result as Mathematica. This is the result
<< Rubi`
Int[x, f[x]]


Maple:
int(x,f(x))


Fricas:
>sage
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath version 10.3, Release Date: 2024-03-19                    │
│ Using Python 3.11.1. Type "help()" for help.                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
sage: var('x')
x
sage: f=function("f",nargs=1)

sage: integrate(f(x),x, algorithm="fricas")
integral(f(x), x)

sage: integrate(x,f(x), algorithm="fricas")

Gives
TypeError: An error occurred when FriCAS evaluated 'integrate(sage4,sage3)':

Maxima:
sage: integrate(x,f(x), algorithm="maxima")
x*f(x)

Giac:
sage: integrate(x,f(x), algorithm="giac")
x*f(x)


The Mathematica result seems to be correct if we assume  Integrate[x, f[x]]==Integrate[x f'[x]],x]
Integration by parts
Integrate[u f'[u],{u,x0,x}]==x f[x]-x0 f[x0]-Integrate[f[u],{u,x0,x}]
differentiate result
D[x f[x]-x0 f[x0]-Integrate[f[u],{u,x0,x}],x] (* x Derivative[1][f][x] *)


Thank you -I specified the details of the question accordingly.

May I ask you why you can differentiate the result? I don't see it.

@oyy I differentiate the result to confirm that  integral Integrate[x f'[x]],x] is correct

But then the Mathematica output is incorrect. Integrate[x,f[x]] should not evaluate to x f[x]. Without differentiation, we should get with integration by parts: Integrate[x f'[x]],x]==x f[x]-Integrate[f[x],x].

Correct, and D[x f[x]-Integrate[f[x],x],x] evaluates to x f'[x]

I see; then I misunderstood your original answer, where you claim that the "Mathematica result seems to be correct if..."
